# Can we have a PDF with countably infinite points at which it blows up?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

I would like to know if there is an example of a probability density function (PDF) $f$ with $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f$ has countable many points $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in its domain such that $f(x_n) = +\infty$?, excluding the Dirac Comb I think this would be impossible to have. Am I correct? I say this because let's say we start with a single point of singularity and replicate that PDF to get another one with two singularities, by squeezing (horizontally) and placing two copies of it at some distance to get a total area of 1. As we keep repeating this procedure countably many times, the sequence would result in Diracs placed at the points $x_n$. This is a very crude and non-rigorous argument, but I would appreciate if someone who is more adept in analysis and probability than I am would contribute, as I am an engineer by training.

**Edit:** I should mention explicitly that the support of the function $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: If you omit continuity, it can be done.  It would be meaningless.  Take any usual density function on the real line and just change it and call it infinite at all rational points.

Comment: What if it is to be contiuous?

Comment: You can use the Lebesgue differentiation Theorem to assign a canonical value of $f(x)$ for almost every value of $x$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: @iconoclast  Answer no. 1 is a good example.  Is it continuous at the integer points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this isn't so bad to do.  Set $g(x) = \begin{cases} |x|^{-1/2} & \text{ if } |x| \leq 1 \\ 
e^{-|x|} & \text{ if } |x| \geq 1
\end{cases}$.  Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \,dx = 4 + 2/e =: C\,.$$

We can then define the p.d.f. $f(x)$ by shifting $g$ to integer points:  $$f(x) = \frac{1}{C}\sum_{j \geq 1} 2^{-j} g(x - j)\,.$$

Then $f$ is continuous everywhere except the natural numbers, at which points it is $+\infty$ and is a p.d.f.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and let
$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |x-r_n|^{-1/2} I_{r_n -1 < x < r_n + 1} .$$
Since ${\|g\|}_1 = 4$, we can use
$$ f = \tfrac14 g .$$